# To insert a substring in the given string:Error:15 [Warning] return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Tags: c

I wish to insert a substring in the main string from the given position c which is user entered but i am constantly getting this warning

Header File:

```
char insstr(char a[100],char b[100],int c){
    int i,j,t;
    while(b[i]!='\0'){
        i++;
    }
    i=t;
    i=0;
    for(j=c;j<t;j++){
        a[j]=b[i];
        i++;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Main File:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include"Q7.h"
main(){
  char x[100],y[100],f;
  printf("Enter the main string \n");
  gets(x);
  printf("Enter the substring \n");
  gets(y);
  printf("Enter the position from where you want to enter the string");
  scanf("%d",f);
  printf("%s",insstr(x,y,f));
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `i=t;` should not be `t = i;` ?

Comment: Your function should return  `char *`, not `char`. And related, the compiler warnings (you *are* compiling with warnings enabled, right?) telling you about use-before-initialiation (ex: `t` in your function) should tell you something.

Comment: Yeah ! Sorry must've been a typo But the problem is in the exchange of the strings

Comment: Well, that "typo" is the reason for the error message you're posting, so perhaps change the question title if the problem is something else. And the use-before-intiailized problem I mentioned earlier also happens with `i` at the beginning of the function).

Answer (score 3):

Strings are usually represented as `char` arrays i.e. `char[]` or `char*`. Since you are returning a string from the function, the return type should be `char*`.

```
char* insstr(char a[100],char b[100],int c)
{
   /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I tried With Char *insstr(....) but the execution stops after taking in all the entries

Comment: There are also some bugs in your function. For example, `i = t` will give a warning because `t` is not initialized. Turn all all warnings in your compiler to catch such problems early.

Comment: @NilayKapadia there are other bugs.. see my comment and others on your question. Also use a debugger to step through your running code and find the exact statement on which it crashes.

Comment: The Debugger says its a segmentation fault

Comment: Is there any other method to insert the string without using the string library to copy a[j] to b[i]

Comment: @NilayKapadia because you are corrupting memory or accessing protected memory. You will have to find that bug on your own - there are many hints in the comments.

Comment: @NilayKapadia The fault happens because your program is ill-formed, invoking *undefined behavior*. And the context of the problem is vague, since the definition of "insert" isn't specified. If `a[]` is `"12345"` and `b[]` is `"xyz"`, should `insstr(a,b,2)` result in `"12xyz"`, or are you expecting `"12xyz345"`? At this point it matters little, however, until you get the dereference math correct. A refresher on terminated strings and use of arrays in C is probably warranted.

Comment: I am expecting "12xyz".

Answer (score 2):

You don't initialize `i` in `insstr()` before using it. This:

```
int i,j,t;
while(b[i]!='\0')
{
    i++;
}
```

Should be:

```
int i,j,t;

i = 0;
while(b[i] != '\0')
{
    i++;
}
```

Or, instead of reinventing the wheel, you should be using `strlen(b)` instead.

This is just wrong:

```
i=t;
i=0;
```

You didn't initialize `t`, and you are assigning to `i` twice. You end up obliterating whatever was stored in `i`. And of course, you are overwriting the contents of `a` without taking care of what was there. You are not inserting a string into `a`, you are replacing part of it with `b`. And then of course, as mentioned in other comments and answers, the return value should be `char *`.

Why not something as simple as this:

```
char *insstr(char *a, char *b, int c)
{
    size_t a_len = strlen(a);
    size_t b_len = strlen(b);
    strcat(a, b);
    reverse(a+c, a_len-c);
    reverse(a+a_len, strlen(b));
    reverse(a+c, a_len-c+b_len);
    return a;
}
```

Where `reverse()` is:

```
void reverse(char *str, size_t len)
{
    size_t i = 0, j = len-1;

    while (i < j)
    {
        char tmp = str[i];
        str[i] = str[j];
        str[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

The algorithm works by concatenating `b` to `a` and then doing the appropriate swaps to move `b` into the right spot. In general, you can think of `a` as a string that can be decomposed into two blocks, `ac`, where `c` is the block after the insertion point where `b` will stay. When you concatenate `b` to the original string, you get `acb`. Moving `b` to the spot before `c` is a matter of reversing `c`, reversing `b`, so that you get `a c_r b_r`, and then you reverse `c_r b_r`, getting `bc` - just what you wanted.

A small example of how to use it:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str1[100] = "Hello!";
    char str2[] = ", world";
    insstr(str1, str2, 5);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
Hello, world!
```

Remember that you must make sure that `a` is indeed large enough to hold `b`. In general, you should pass the size of `a` as an argument, so that you can take appropriate action if `a` is not big enough, or, alternatively, you can make your code ensure that `insstr()` is not called if `a` is not big enough.

And please don't use `gets()`. Always use `fgets()`. It doesn't hurt, it is not complex, and it shows that you care.

**NOTE**: this idea is generalized in the book *Programming Pearls* as an efficient and elegant way to implement string rotations (which is what you want after appending `b`). Off the top of my head, I *think* it is mentioned in the "Aha! Algorithms" column.

Comment: +1 Despite the fact that this answer fails to answer the *actual* question, you did answer a whole bunch of questions that the OP should have asked, meant to ask, didn't know enough to ask, etc.

Comment: @Caleb True. It doesn't answer this specific question, but I think it is actually more useful to the OP. I couldn't let this slip by without showing this alternative way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int insstr ( char *str, char *ins, int at) {
    int each;
    int len = 0;
    int lenstr = 0;
    int lenins = 0;

    while ( str[lenstr] != '\0') {
        lenstr++;
    }
    while ( ins[lenins] != '\0') {
        lenins++;
    }

    if ( at > lenstr) {
        at = lenstr; // force at to length of str if needed
    }

    len = at;
    for ( each = 0; each <= lenins; each++) {
        str[len] = ins[each]; // append ins onto str
        len++;
    }

    return 1; // return true
}

int main() {
    char input[300];
    char substr[300];
    char position[300];
    int insert;
    int each;

    printf ( "Enter a string.\n");
    fgets ( input, sizeof ( input), stdin);
    each = 0;
    while ( input[each] != '\n') {
        each++;
    }
    input[each] = '\0'; // remove new-line

    printf ( "Enter sub-string.\n");
    fgets ( substr, sizeof ( substr), stdin);
    each = 0;
    while ( substr[each] != '\n') {
        each++;
    }
    substr[each] = '\0'; // remove new-line

    printf ( "Enter position to insert sub-string.\n");
    fgets ( position, sizeof ( position), stdin);
    insert = atoi ( position); // make position an integer

    if ( insstr ( input, substr, insert)) {
        printf ( "%s\n", input); // insert is successful. print it.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There should be no usage of string library.

Comment: @NilayKapadia: You may want to mention such a 'minor' detail in your post.